# Python pip3 install StringIO Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/stringio/

Tags: python-3.x, pip, stringio

I am running python version 3.6.9 and pip3 version 9.0.1. when i execute the command

```
pip3 install StringIO
```

It returns the error

```
Collecting StringIO
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/stringio/
```

Do you know how to fix this error.

Manny thank 
Erik

Comment: In Python 3 `StringIO` is built-in to Python in the `io` module. So you'd do `from io import StringIO`. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks that is the solution!!  How do you know what is builtin and which function are not built in?

Comment: You should always search for information regarding the function you wish to use, and from that information you'll know which is built-in and not.

Comment: Please consult the python documentation, which details which modules are built in.

Comment: Python standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/; version-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use **pip3**:

[image]

**Use:**

```
import io

hi = io.StringIO("hi")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Python3 String IO is a built-in function in the IO module. To work with this module 
i must use:

```
from io import StringIO
```